# I want to implement a Smoothy transition from nowrap to normal

Tags: html, css

I want to create a fixed width table which may contain long string in one td.
but I don't want it to warp up to another line when display it.

I want it to display the full content when user hover on the row where is the td place into.

The smoothy transition effect is in the example I made. I want that effect without setting fixed height.

Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
        <td>This is a testing Message that longer than the td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

table tr td{
  margin:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  height:25px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1),table tr td:nth-child(2){
  width:30%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
  width:40%;
}

table tr:hover td{
  white-space:normal;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:visible;
  text-overflow:inherit;
  height:150px;
}
```

The effect that I want its [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3grbLcen/)

However, if I want this smoothy transition effect, I have to set a fixed height for the `td`. But my desired result is the `td` will expand base on the content length (how many line the content wrap).

Hope someone can help me with this, thanks

Comment: Define "beautiful." That's your job to the browser.

Comment: HI i have define it, and edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  min-height property in css instead of height, so that it can increase as per content.

you can try this example:
[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)